# Shorten Redundant if statements Into a single Method (Java)

Tags: java, user-interface, methods

How can I write this section of code within a method to make this shorter? Is there a way to take the input and use that for the action? Example: User enters in white and it will replace x in bgColor = Color.x; I'm just trying to get rid of all of the if statements.

```
    sg.print("Please enter a background color");

    String colorString = sg.keyReadString();
    Color bgColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;

    if("white".equalsIgnoreCase(colorString))
    {
        bgColor = Color.WHITE;
    }
    else if("red".equalsIgnoreCase(colorString))
    {
        bgColor = Color.RED;
    }
    else if("orange".equalsIgnoreCase(colorString))
    {
        bgColor = Color.ORANGE;
    }
    else if("yellow".equalsIgnoreCase(colorString))
    {
        bgColor = Color.YELLOW;
    }
    else if("green".equalsIgnoreCase(colorString))
    {
        bgColor = Color.GREEN;
    }
    else if("blue".equalsIgnoreCase(colorString))
    {
        bgColor = Color.BLUE;
    }
    else if("gray".equalsIgnoreCase(colorString))
    {
        bgColor = Color.GRAY;
    }
    else if("magenta".equalsIgnoreCase(colorString))
    {
        bgColor = Color.MAGENTA;
    }
    else if("cyan".equalsIgnoreCase(colorString))
    {
        bgColor = Color.CYAN;
    }
    else if("pink".equalsIgnoreCase(colorString))
    {
        bgColor = Color.PINK;
    }
    else
    {
        sg.print("couldn't understand your color, so defaulting to black");
    }

    sg.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
```

Comment: How's a `Map<String, Color>` sound?

Comment: I'm just learning java this semester so I'm a little confused. Can you explain?

Comment: doing such a thing would create problems if the user enters a color that isn't in the Color class, or misspells a color. You would have to have a check to see if the color is valid which would end up being the same sort of long "if then" checking.
you could search for "switch statement in java" to see a cleaner way to do long "if then" statements.
but if you are not worried about possible errors, I'm not sure of a way to do such a thing in java.

Comment: In that case it will probably be unacceptable. It's a data structure that would allow you to do `bgColor = colorMap.get(colorString);`

Comment: @Frobot, those are trivial problems (I'd say). A switch is probably "best" for this case since they're just starting out but the fact that users are a big source of errors doesn't mean we through proper data structs out the window.

Comment: @Frobot, and it doesn't require as much as you have in a switch. A switch is basically the same length as the if-else chain while using a map could do the check and assignment with a single line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Or you can easily put all your required colors into a map and filter given color form the map**

```
Color bgColor;
String givenColor="blUe";
Map<String, Color> colors = new HashMap<>();
colors.put("RED", Color.RED);
colors.put("BLUE", Color.BLUE);
colors.put("WHITE", Color.WHITE);
colors.put("GREEN", Color.GREEN);

bgColor=colors.get(givenColor.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: if you have map, why do you need to loop through it to get the value based on the key? colors.get(givenColor.toUpperCase()) will be sufficient.

Comment: Yes .. Thank u BOND :)

Answer (score 1):

In java 7 or above, you can use switch on string to make your logic more concise. Convert string to lower case first so that you don't need to worry about the case of the user input.

```
String colorString = sg.keyReadString().toLowerCase();

    switch (colorString) {
        case "white":
            bgColor = Color.WHITE;
            break;
        case "red":
            bgColor = Color.RED;
            break;
        case "orange":
            bgColor = Color.ORANGE;
            break;
        case "yellow":
            bgColor = Color.YELLOW;
            break;
        case "green":
            bgColor = Color.GREEN;
            break;
        default:
            bgColor = DEFAULT_OPTION;
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A short and quick way would be to do the following

```
Color bgColor = (Color) Color.class.getDeclaredField(colorString.toUpperCase()).get(null);

if(gbColor == null) {
    bgColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    sg.print("couldn't understand your color, so defaulting to black");
}
```